# Why do some of the scenes in the 5th Episode of Attack on Titan differ when it was aired in Fukuoka?

Tags: anime-production, attack-on-titan

The airing of the 5th episode of Attack on Titan in Fukuoka (see top in the Youtube video below) had some noticeable differences from the original airing (see bottom).

Why were these changes made? Was it due to censorship or production issues?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jaRBxrzNMs

Comment: Can you summarize what was in the video? The link is now dead because the account that uploaded it was removed.

Comment: @FAE I've replaced the link.

Comment: @Krazer, Link is down...

Comment: @Pacerier not anymore!

Comment: @Krazer, Why did you not embed the video in instead?

Comment: @Pacerier: Not supported by SE, AFAIK.

Comment: @Pacerier Youtube embedding is enabled on a per-site basis. While I [requested it here](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/434/can-we-get-embedded-youtube-videos), it hasn't yet been enabled. To get SE to consider enabling it, one needs to find examples of answers which would be significantly improved by embedding the video as opposed to linking. Until then, links are the best we can do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the video you linked, the uploader also linked to a news post on the Attack on Titan anime's official website. This news post explains the situation. I've translated the most relevant part:

> 各放送局のオンエアー日を極力揃えて放送しておりますが、 この度は制作上及び放送局納品期限の都合により、このような放送形態となりました。
>
> Although we tried our hardest to deliver the same product to
>   each broadcasting office on the day of the airing, due to certain
>   circumstances involving the episode as well as the broadcast office's
>   deadline, the broadcast ended up like this.

Source: [Attack on Titan news post](http://shingeki.tv/news/archives/167)

Seems like the staff were running a little too close to their deadlines and ended up not having the finished product for all stations. I think it would be safe to assume that stations that aired the unfinished version had stricter deadlines.